# Will Tunnel Bear ever be supported on Ubuntu?

Tags: vpn

I have used tons of VPNs, and I really don't like any except TunnelBear.  I need something that I can set my location with.  If there is a good alternative that is available with Ubuntu please let me know because I have not found one even for Windows.

So, will Ubuntu ever support TunnelBear?  It would be really nice if they would do this soon.

Comment: There is tunneldigger in ubuntu. Can install with `sudo apt-get install tunneldigger debhelper fakeroot make openssl perl`

Comment: From your comment about the set location feature, it seems you are searching VPN service, not VPN protocol.  Some sites says that tunnelbear support openvpn, which is perfectly supported on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

**It may be supported shortly**

...because TunnelBear already has some limited support for linux (including Ubuntu), since the end of march 2014.

In this post [TunnelBear befriend penguin](https://www.tunnelbear.com/development/linux_support/) it is stated that users with a Giant or Grizly account (paid) can connect to the VPN. Tunnelbear provides users with openvpn profiles (for each country you wan't to connect to).

Software (openvpn) is very easy to install `sudo apt-get install openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome`.

Answer (score 0):

[TunnelBear befriend penguin](https://www.tunnelbear.com/development/linux_support/) post mentioned above helped me. I am running Ubuntu 18.04.1. LTS and I was able to make the VPN connection work. Make sure to install openvpn like Remi shared above.

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

Good Luck.